# Angular UI Router - onEnter not get the $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

According this [FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state) this code should work:

```
$stateProvider.state("items.add", {
    url: "/add",
    onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$modal', '$resource', function($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {
        console.log($stateParams.param1); // should print "bla bla bla" but $stateParams.param1 isnot defined;
    }],
    url: "/test",
    onEnter: ['$state', function($state){
        $state.go('add', {param1: 'bla bla bla'});
    }
});
```

And should print "bla bla bla"..

Can anyone tell me why its not working?

Answer (score 1):

This code has multiple syntax errors and I don't see how could've run this (missing `]`, duplicate properties in the same object, etc).

My best guess is that you haven't defined the `param1` parameter. You can't use arbitrary parameters when transitioning to a state, they must either be part of the URL or defined in the `params` state argument.

Comment: Sorry for the broken code, i have the same code om my side i just changed things due to NDA :)

Regard the params, i tried to add "params" to the state dictionary but still dont work for me.

Comment: When anonymizing code you should take extra care not to break it. That only adds confusion. Could you update your code with the changes you made (and remove the errors while you're at it)?